# Visual Studio 6 VC++ Project version - how do I increment it?

Tags: c++, versioning, increment, visual-studio-6

I am making changes to an old program written in VC++6. the project resources include a 'version' set which include the following:
Block Header
Comments
Company Name
File Version
Product Version

Both FileVersion and ProductVersion are at 1.0.0.97 (where the 97 is a build number and increments each time I build the project)

My changes are such that I ought to increment one of the other numbers. It should probably go to 1.0.1. but even though I can edit these strings, as soon as I build the project, the 1st three numbers revert to 1.0.0. Does anyone know where these numbers are really held and how to change them?

These numbers and settings also go into the executable file's 'properties'. The build date is held in the 'Comments' resource string which I think is crap and would like to have it automatically generated as well: I am not going to remember to check it before every build!

Any suggestions gratefully received.

--- Alistair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are in an rc .file

Open the resource editor and look in the version tab/section.

If you make the changes and save it then they should remain that way.  I would check to see if there is any other task or something that is overwriting those.

Note that one of the fields (I forget which) is a "slave" of another one.  Post up the resource file (or at least the section with the version info)

You can use a #include for the version info so that you have only one place for the version information.

Comment: D'oh!
If you don't save the resources file, it silently throws your changes away! Many thanks.

Comment: Not the first one to be bitten by this.  Normally I think my IDE does a save all prior to compilation to avoid this - might check your settings for that.  I have no idea where that is.